# cd or ls not found?

Tags: ubuntu, ls

All commands have been working until a few days ago on our Ubuntu server. When running `ls` or `cd` it returns `bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: `ls` is a binary so a faulty `PATH` environment could be to blame as many folks have suggested.  However, `cd` is also a shell builtin, which should be working.  Does it report exactly the same error?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `ls` executable is missing. `ls` is part of the coreutils package on Debian-based systems, so you might want to see if it's been uninstalled.

You can use `aptitude`:

```
runejuhl@lapaz:~$ aptitude search ^coreutils$
i coreutils                      - GNU core utilities
```

In the above, the "i" in the beginning of the line means that the package is indeed installed.

Comment: `ls` is installed.

Comment: Hmm. What does `stat -c '%A %n' /bin/ls` tell you? It should be something like this: `-rwxr-xr-x /bin/ls`

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, the same message would be generated in this situation: /bin/ls binary is replaced with a shell script, but this shell script has an invalid bang line (for example if it starts with `#!/this/does/not/exist`). Hmmm, rootkit?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/environment` file to make sure it still specifies the path. The default Ubuntu (as of 9.10) has just one line in it:

`PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"`

That one line gets pulled into various sub-systems that handle login however. Setting the PATH elsewhere can mess Ubuntu's GDM up.

Comment: It still shows the path.